# Np array shape (1,X,X) to (X,X)

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Is it possible to reshape and np array and to avoid the first list of dimension 1 that is not relevant?

```
array.shape  (1,X,X)
to
array2.shape (X,X)
```

Comment: array2 = array[0] ?

Comment: array.squeeze()

Comment: dammit forgive me for that, hours of coding cannot see clear...

Answer (score 2):

`array = array.reshape(X,X)`

-- or --

`array = array[0]`

Answer (score 1):

You can remove axis with dimension 1 from arrays using [squeeze](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html) method.

```
array = np.random.randn(1, 10, 10) 
array = array.squeeze() 
print(array.shape)
# (10, 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the shape:

```
array.shape = array.shape[1:]
```